# ARKit – 3D objects are not static

Tags: swift, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

My ARKit application places certain 3D objects in space, but only some of them remain stationary and the rest follow me around as I walk.

Does object anchoring depend on the specific object? I download my objects from `turbosquid.com` and use the `OBJ` versions of them.

Answer (score 0):

For Objects to remain stationary (relative to you) it is important to attach them as children of the `SCNView`'s root node using something like:

```
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(you3dModelNode)
```

If you want the nodes to move with you, you can add them as children of the camera node. (*Which is not the behavior you are looking for*)

*Note: To receive a more tailored response, please update the question to include some of the code you have tried.*